# Fire Render Times

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, settings

so I'm new to using fire in my animations. I have a 4090 for GPU but wow my renders are taking so long for just simple fire burst animation. Are there settings I should be doing to get a faster render? My graphics card is extremely fast and this is just nuts. One frame is taking 20 mins.

Samples are 150
1920x1080

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: TBH volumetric shaders **are** some of the slowest things to render, so it isn't unexpected to have a significant increase of render time as soon as you add them in your scene. Now there are ways to optimize things here and there or even fake volumetrics to some degree. But it would help if you could share your file here using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/). Or at least post screenshots of your render settings and shaders. Ideally do both!

Comment: Ok posted some screen grabs showing shaders/render.

Comment: Hmmm... I only have a 3060 but my fire renders don't take that long usually with 150 samples. But of course this is not only dependent on the render samples but also on the resolution of the smoke domain for example. How detailed is your fire animation? The more voxels per image, the longer the render time. Also motion blur slows down the render times. By the way, to not get frustrated after a long render and then seeing black artifacts in the fire/smoke, I would increase the _Transparency_ bounces. That doesn't increase render times very much - I usually have them at 64 or 128.

Comment: @SteveCady Have you tried rendering without _Motion Blur_? I just made a test render myself (on this computer I only have a 1060), 1920 × 1080 with 150 samples (and volume bounce at 1 and 128 transparency bounces) and it took only 1 minute 20 seconds - **without** _Motion Blur_. Now I enabled it and **with** _Motion Blur_ the the render took 15:49 minutes. So from 80 seconds to 949 seconds is almost 1200%... quite a leap.

Comment: I forgot: screenshots of your domains settings would absolutely help. The most sensitive setting is the domain's resolution if I remember correctly, also adaptive domain if you don't bake your simulation before rendering (which you should NOT do, especially when using motion blur), also noise i think, ... Motion Blur is **definitely** [a big weight in render times](https://studio.blender.org/blog/cycles-turbocharged-how-we-made-rendering-10x-faster/).

Comment: Enabling [path guiding](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.4/Cycles#Path_Guiding) can help too (although available for CPU rendering and some GPUs as of v3.4, see previous link).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was turning off the motion blur. Huge time saver fix! Worst case if I'm desperate for motion blur for this moment I can add it in after effects. Thank you Gordon!